# Unable to keep data in database when leaving and entering VS

Tags: sql, database

I am using SQL Server 2008 in a Visual Basic 2010 application.
I can enter data thru the application and not see any problems. But when I exit Visual Studio and then start Visual Studio and open my project the data i proviously entered is gone.

Comment: I've been experiencing the same problem for about a week now. Have you tried building the solution, opening your program up (outside of SQL) and seeing if it takes the data? Additionally, what controls are you using to view the data in you XAML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you import the .mdf to your project? If so, check to ensure you are not over-writing it each time you start your project.

Comment: I have a Visual Basic application that I use to access an SQL 2008 database. When I add a record to my table everything appears to be fine. As long as I keep visual studio running the data remains in the database. But if I exit visual studio and then reopen visual studio the data in the table is gone. I selected my SQL Server database from the Add New Item dialog. I selected service-based database. Instead of creating the database from the server explorer.I am using stored procedures to enter data. Could this property of the database "Copy to output directories" = Copy Always, be the proplem?

Comment: @robblot: I think you are going to have to show us some code.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try to explain "I can enter data through the application" further. In what way do you enter data? Do you perform INSERTs to the database? How do you validate that the data is persisted (in your database)?

Unless your running a TRUNCATE on application start, the data should still be there :-)

Also, if you run SQL Server locally, it runs as a service outside VS, so restarting VS won't affect it.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is that the post-er was casting the data to the wrong type of collection so that the data was never "committed" to the database, only manipulations were tracked until the connection to the data was closed upon shutting down the program. I had this problem when I first began databinding in Visual Studio, as i would drag columns from the Data Source window as listViews or labels, etc. onto my project which were automatically cast by Visual Studio as ViewSources. Once I began using "ObservableCollections" and setting up my own data classes, this problem stopped happening. If you're going to be working with something like a DataGrid, you're going to have to cast your data into some type of List, CollectionView, or ObservableCollection, rather than just using the usual "ViewSource."